# Is it possible to UNION ALL a prepared statement and a select statement?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write up something that can be run once and exported with all the data from a prepared statement and a select statement. Is it possible to union them?

example dynamic pivot table

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'format(sum(case when field_key = ''',
      field_key,
      ''' then field_value end), 0) ',
      field_key
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Meeting_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Meeting 
                   GROUP BY Meeting_id'
                 );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

example select statement

```
set @startdate = '2020-11-10'
set @enddate = '2020-12-30'

select column1,
       column2,   
       column3,
       if(col.id = id,1,0) column4,
       if(col.id = id,0,1) column5
from Meeting
group by col.id
order by column2;
```

If its not possible to UNION ALL them then what would be your suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can concatenate `UNION ALL ...` in the prepared statement. But do the two queries return the same number of columns?

Comment: They do not have the same number of columns

Comment: Then how do you expect to union them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unions have to have the same number of columns (and their names are taken from the first query in the union), and here the pivot query has a dynamic number.  You would need to adjust the columns of your second select to match and add it to your `@sql` as a union.

Often with unions you add a type field that is hardcoded and different for each of the unioned queries, and have each query return null for columns that aren't relevant to that query.